# HTML POST Submit button not working

Tags: html, post, button

I got my page which is a simple password unlocker, but the post submit form button won't work...

```
<div class="content">
            <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
                <div class="user-profile">        
                    <div class="author">
                        <img class="avatar" src="../../assets/img/default-avatar.png" alt="...">
                    </div> 
                    <h4>User Unlock</h4> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round btn-fil btn-wd">Unlock</button>                                 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

When I click the button nothing happens..

It does not redirect to action_page.php nor sends any data.

Answer (score 0):

Check new version.

You added `<button>`. You need to add `<input type="submit">` .
Like this:

```
<div class="content">
            <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
                <div class="user-profile">        
                    <div class="author">
                        <img class="avatar" src="../../assets/img/default-avatar.png" alt="...">
                    </div> 
                    <h4>User Unlock</h4> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round btn-fil btn-wd" value="Unlock">                                 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Thanks, he was first and this is already fixed now, thanks all for replies.

Answer (score -1):

if action_page.php is in the same folder as the current page, you don't need backslash. So change it into

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
```

also, you must declare the button as submit if you want to get redirected to action_page.php

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round btn-fil btn-wd">Unlock</button>
```

Comment: @OrangeOrange: what you know about file structure, the OP didn't write nothing.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, but it works. I misreaded the code, thanks :)